# How can I report on iOS and Android memory and process parameters inside my Xamarin.Forms application?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have an application and I'm concerned that after running a long time it might be using too much memory.  Perhaps there are some memory or background process issues that I need to look into.

Is there a way that I can find out from within both an iOS and Android application some memory and process statistics.  If I was to be able to get to these I know how how to do the UI to report on them but I'm just not sure how to get the information.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/tools/profiler/?tabs=vsmac

Answer (score 0):

[image: Go to Tools->Instruments]

[image: Select Acitivity Monitor and then Select device you want to run Activity Monitor on]

Bear in my that by default it will be your mac Device selected device. Change it to your phone or Simulator.